# How do I trigger an event via Google Tag Manager when the user clicks the 'Add To Cart' text (not button) on a Squarespace product page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, squarespace

first time question asker here.

I am looking to trigger an event via Google Tag Manager when the user clicks the 'Add To Cart' text (not button) on a Square Space product page i.e. http://shop.ryanputn.am/all/custom-ebbets-sig-cap

The Add To Cart text container code looks like this:
[div class="sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner"]Add To Cart[/div]

As it isn't a button, I assume I have to use click text, where click text is equal to Add To Cart, this doesn't seem like the most efficient installation though.

Is there a better way, is it easier to use a JS push event?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom event trigger & use event name gtm.click with element classes contains sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner

Comment: In GTM v2 a event with the name gtm.click can be used much simpler by setting the trigger type to "click"  (and maybe select "links only" and uncheck "wait for tags" and "valid urls only").

Comment: The button isn't a link so the Targets would be All Elements and than fire on element classes contains sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner